# The history of number in percent locutions

Tags: grammatical-number, historical-change, percentages

It seems that

> Ten percent of the pie *is* eaten

is now universally? considered correct.  **Was there a time in the history
of modern English when this was not so?**  That is, when *are* would have
been preferred?

---

For the record, I think a reasonable sentence analysis is the
following.

- is/are : verb
- ten percent : subject (plural)
- of the pie : modifier of percent, which is subordinate to it

The current practice, I take it, is a contructio ad sensum (synesis),
like when one says *mathematics is fun,* *that's good news,* or *a means
to an end.* The verb form is determined by the ''logical'' subject (the
pie-piece) rather then the grammatical subject *(ten percent).*

Comment: Ten percent of the marbles are green.  Ten percent of the orange juice is wasted.

Comment: Related: [**Technicalities about “%”?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113203/technicalities-about) and [**Is “89.9%” singular or plural?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217929/is-89-9-singular-or-plural/217930#217930)

Comment: The answer to this question is relevant: [has vs have on a singular noun that represents a plural idea](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421618/has-vs-have-on-a-singular-noun-that-represents-a-plural-idea?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: "Ten percent of the pie are eaten" is never correct. It's a singular quantity.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree that is how it is now, but the question is whether that was always the case.  Especially if you go back to when "per cent" was two words and "10%" may have been more readily considered equivalent to saying "ten parts in a hundred", making the implied "parts" the (plural) subject.

Comment: Going back in history "a tenth part" was common usage. I can't think of any examples of a plural usage.