# Subject-verb agreement while talking about percent

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which one of the following two sentences is the correct sentence?

- "20% of the participants **believe** that the world is flat."
- "20% of the participants **believes** that the world is flat."

What grammatical rules govern the choice of the correct sentence here?

Comment: Plural "believe" is the one you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Technicalities about "%"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113203/technicalities-about) Please check out the answer from Tchrist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a percentage quantity take singular or plural verb agreement?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273585/does-a-percentage-quantity-take-singular-or-plural-verb-agreement) See Matt E. Эллен's answer, and my caveat. Would you say '20% of them has died'??? Even with a singular-form collective/group noun, I'd use notional agreement. '20% of the staff have died.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *20% of the participants believes*/*believe that the world is flat*

The noun "percent" (or just %) belongs with the number-transparent nouns like "lot" and "number", where the number of the whole noun phrase depends not on the head, but on the number of the noun that is complement to the preposition "of".

In this case, the complement of "of" is the plural noun "participants", so the NP requires the plural verb "believe".